# Why is setRelation() not working properly in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I have the following code:

```
if (!$this->relationLoaded('feed')) {
    $this->getFeed();
}
```

then in the getFeed() method i have the following:

```
public function getFeed() {
    $feed = Cache::get(RSSFeed::CACHE_KEY . $this->id_RSSFeed, function() {
        $feed = $this->feed;

        Cache::put(RSSFeed::CACHE_KEY . $this->id_RSSFeed, $feed, now()->addHours(24));

        return $feed;
    });

    // not empty
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($feed);

    $this->setRelation('feed', $feed);

    // empty
    print_r($this->feed);
    exit;

    return $this->feed;
}
```

I also have the feed() relationship defined as following:

```
public function feed() {
    return $this->belongsTo("App\RSSFeed", "id_RSSFeed");
}
```

Now for some reason, when I try to do a `print_r()` on `$this->feed` after setting the relation on `$this`, it returns null or empty. What am I doing wrong here? Am I using the wrong method to do this? Any help you guys can give would be appreciated.

edit: I forgot that at the top of the class I had the following:

```
class RSSFeed extends Model {
    public $feed;
}
```

So that was overwriting the relation. I'll add an answer shortly in case this messes up other people.

Comment: See answer in following link.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62751423/6229824

Answer (score 0):

so as posted in the question in an edit, this was the culprit:

```
class RSSFeed extends Model {
    public $feed;
}
```

once I removed `public $feed;` from there it started working properly