# setrelation method doesn't work in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My user relationship is :

```
    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
    }
```

and the query is :

```
  $user = User::with('country')->first();
```

I want to check if the country is empty replace that with a default data or anything

so first I tried like this :

```
if(empty($user->country)){
$user->country = "some default value";
}
```

and It didn't work after searching I try this :

```
if(empty($user->country)){
$user->setRelation('country' , 'some default value');
}
```

and again it doesn't work for me. the "setRelation" remove the country key in the user's object

Comment: if you `dd($user)` do you get `#relations: array:1 [▶]` ??

Comment: no it's collection { items:[] }

Comment: `$user` is a collection?

Comment: I think the user is the instance of model

Comment: App\Model\User {#1582
...
}

Comment: then you should find the relationships with an array. look at the lower part when you do dd. or take a screen shot and share it with us.

Comment: I can change the other property like fullname , username , ... but the relationship doesn't change so I unset the country from object and set it again with my default data

Comment: just `dd($user)` and check if relation loads. have tested myself. found no problem using `$user->setRelation('country' , 'some default value');`. get `some default value` when i do `$user->country`.

Comment: yes if you return $user->country it returns the some defautt value but if you return the $user it does n't return the country

Comment: how are you accessing $user in the frontend??

Answer (score 1):

If empty / null received in eloquent result `relation` key, then set `defaultOject` can be set as follows:

For single relation:

```
$modelInstance = $modelInstance->setRelation('relationName', $relationModelObject)
```

For multiple relation:

```
$modelInstance = $modelInstance->setRelation('relationName', collect([$relationModelObject]))
```

Multiple relation example:

```
$defaultMedia = new Media;
$defaultMedia->id = 0;
$defaultMedia->file_name = 'defaultImage.jpg';

$result = Post::with('media')->get();

$result->transform(function ($post, $key) use($defaultMedia) {
    if($post->media->count() == 0) {
        $post->setRelation('media', collect([$defaultMedia]));
    }
    return $post;
});

return $result;
```

Now, in final `$result` you shall get `$defaultMedia` when `relation` returned `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work that way because *country* is not a direct attribute/column of the user.

You can change your code like this.

```
if(empty($user->country)){
   $user->country->update([
     'name' => "some default value"
   ]);
}
```

Hope it works. :-)

Comment: Yes, You can use it when you want to update relation in eloquent.